# Limit the possible values of a column SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an table which look like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    type CHAR(1)
);
```

I already know that the column `type` will only have four possible value "a", "b", "c" or "d".

Is there a way to limit the possible value of the column to those four or do I need to do it from my code rather than in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add check constraint :

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable
    MODIFY type CHAR(1) NOT NULL CHECK (type in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'));
```